# Does JavaScript have function parameter types?

Tags: javascript, function, types, parameters, default

In PHP you can set function parameters (Or as there called in PHP arguements) to only accept a certain type(s) and a default value. Is this possible in JavaScript?

```
function test(bool $a = false) {
    
}
```

In the Atom code editor, when I type for example 'text'.substring() and I hover over the code, a tooltip window says this...

```
(Method) String.substring(start: number, end?: number)
```

The reason I want to be able to set the parameter types is to have this tooltip be accurate on my custom functions.

Comment: Typescript adds the concept of variable types, in the context that you are asking about.

Comment: typeof arguments[0] === ...

Comment: JavaScript has default values, it doesn't have parameter types.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question. Please read to see why I ask this question.

Comment: @StackSlave I updated the question. Please read to see why I ask this question.

Comment: IDEs like Atom get this information from jsdoc comments.

Comment: @Barmar so this is not possible for custom functions in JS and Atom reads this from the jsdoc to help programmers understand the parameter types on the fly and does not get this from the JS language itself?

Comment: Right, since the language itself doesn't have this information. That's why documentation comments were invented.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables don't have any types, but you can make a custom tooltip, possibly based off of comments inserted into the parameters of the functions, usin the Tooltip manager https://goodfoodgoodcode.com/2016/10/01/custom-tooltips-in-the-atom-text-editor/